# elasticsearch 7.16.2 bootstrap failed because of The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch 7.16.2 bootstrap failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException, The Security Manager is deprecated an will be removed in a future release....

check whether JDK is supported(supported), try to config security.manager.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml，also failed ---> showed the same exception.